# Why does sphinx 3.4.1 return zeros when creating a query via SetSelect()

Tags: php, search, sphinx

I am using sphinx 3.4.1 and php 7.4.
I have a [sql_attr_multi](https://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.3.2.html#conf-sql-attr-multi) field
and when I filter its data through [`setFilterRange()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20210427222344/https://www.php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setfilterrange.php), the data is returned correct
However, if I do this via [`setSelect()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20210427222625/https://www.php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setselect.php), for example

```php
$sphinx->setSelect(
    "*, IF(((field>= {$min} and field <={$max}) OR (field>= {$min1} and field <={$max1})), 1, 0) as fromField"
);
$sphinx->setFilter('fromField', [1]);
```

then the objects of the field field come as '0', which is why I get data only if `$min = 0`.

Even without using 'OR' I get the same results

```php
$sphinx->setSelect(
    "*, IF(((field>= {$min} and field <={$max})), 1, 0) as fromField"
);
```

I need to filter this field with the logical operator 'OR'.

I'm not sure if the problem is part of the sql_attr_multi field, because for the sql_attr_uint field, this sort works

Comment: _"Why is this happening? What could be the problem?"_ - this is not a good way to ask on stackoverflow. Better add your own understanding you currently have, so it becomes clear what puzzles you and you ask more concrete. In it's current form, you invite others to guess and speculate, that won't give you good feedback. [edit] the question and tell us a bit more in your own words. Similar for "I tried a thousand ways", what if the answer is: you need to combine way #42 (because always the answer) with way #632? (Yes I know this _is_ the answer ^^).

Comment: It looks like the library you're using is not maintained any longer ( https://pecl.php.net/package/sphinx ) - Is this the library you have in use? Please document the PHP version and the sphinx library version and provide reference where you obtained it from so that the context of your question becomes more clear. And welcome to Stack Overflow, you can always [edit] your question.